# How to keep special characters in J-query?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My `jquery` string has special characters as follows.

```js
$(window).load(function() {  
  var text = 'Hi there, I'm 5'5" height';
  alert (text); // out put without ' " signs
});
```

i want to print same as it is the out put. How to do it? In `PHP` it does by `htmlspecialchars` function.
Required output is

```
Hi there, I'm 5'5" height
```

Comment: FYI this has nothing to do with jQuery - it's a "problem" you'd have in vanilla JS too as that's how strings are interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the quotes using `\`

```js
  var text = 'Hi there, I\'m 5\'5\" height';
  alert (text); // out put without ' " signs
```

Comment: Is there any special function to do it for bulk of text. I meant texts come from database.